# Can not boot Ubuntu 11.10 from external USB HDD

Tags: 11.10, installation, boot, usb

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10 x64 on a 200Gb partition of my 2Tb external usb HDD. Everything went smoothly. After restarting the computer, I tried hitting F12 and choosing usb hdd. Something like 'Loading operating system' showed up, then it booted into windows. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Check this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/123568/usb-boot-is-skipping-and-reverting-the-hdd/123797

Comment: Mine doesn't boot even when I disconnect the internal HDD, so I doubt that's the problem. I'll use the code you wrote and give the results.

Comment: Since I can't boot into the system, I had to do it by booting from installation USB. It gives some error like 'Cannot find /boot/grub/menu.lst'

Comment: I had a similar problem, the message was `No boot sector on USB device`. See [my answer in this other thread](http://askubuntu.com/a/350762/181442) to fix it, which (re-)installs grub onto the USB drive after installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your external hard drive as primary boot device instead of the F12 boot menu option.

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Same thing happens(loading operating system->Windows).